# Return all string matching the given pattern regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to return all string matching a regex.

```
let text = "data.check && Obj[data.check]['display_119']) {  1549: displayName = obj[data.check]['display_12']";

var identifiers = text.match("display_[0-9]+$");
```

`identifiers` should be an array containing

```
["display_119", "display_12"]; //expected
```

Comment: You can omit the `$` like `var identifiers = text.match(/display_[0-9]+/g);`

Comment: You are matching a string, not a regular expression

Comment: `text.match(/display_[0-9]+/g);`

Answer (score 2):

To get the expected result, you should transform the string you're passing to `match()` in a regular expression. Also, as commented, you're not expecting results that are only at the end of `text`, so you don't need `$` in your RegExp.

```js
let text = "data.check && Obj[data.check]['display_119']) {  1549: displayName = obj[data.check]['display_12']";

var identifiers = text.match(/display_[0-9]+/g);

console.log(identifiers)
```